# A variable across the whole application

Tags: c++, windows, dll, static

I have a C++ windows application which is composed of several DLLs.
I want to have some sort of a pool from which I'll get objects, but in a way that this pool
would be available in all the DLLs.
So I put it in a "Common" dll which everbody has access to and defined it in a header file like so:
static Pool globalPool;

I do have access from every dll but this pool is created many many times.
I think it happens in each of my DLLs and in each File which include the header file with the definition.

How can I do it properly?
thanks :)

Comment: Casual globals are already eeeevil. I don't want to invent a new word for this, so just forget about it, okay? :)

Comment: @delnan. Every time someone asks a smart question which is somehow tough to answer people start saying "Forget about it". Yes, if it's a bad style, it's a bad style and should be pointed out, but ONLY if you have a better alternative to propose.  And globals are not evil if used smartly and appropriately

Comment: @deInan - almost sounds like the Session object in ASP.NET, what a f*@cking nightmare....

Comment: @Armen: (1) You noticed that my comment is somewhat tongue-in-cheek? (2) But anyway, it *does* sound like something complicated that's propably not needed. (3) I'd suggest something else, but there are no details on the *problem* at hand, so I can't think of a solution. (4) Globals are not always evil, yes. They are okay if absolutely necessary or in small programs that don't need (much) maintenance. The former is very rare, the latter isn't the case here (as the program is so large that is spans multiple DLLs).

Comment: more details? what would you like to know?

Comment: @Armen: I don't think it's possible to suggest anything "better" without knowing what it's for, and also agreeing on the definition of "better". Some people insist that any negative judgment has to be accompanied by a "better" alternative, with undefined "better". I think that's just a way to attempt to avoid critique. I think the best way to come up with "better" alternatives is to identify the problems and have two or three or more minds thinking about it. Not the other way around, first finding "better" and then identify problem. :-) Cheers,

Comment: @delnan: don't take it too personally, I mean it was an outburst because it is far too common when a specific question is being asked but most/answers comments regard style or other aspects which are not being asked leaving the main question unanswered. It is OK (but not always, and even not usually) to address other issues as well, but not forgetting about the specific question being asked. Again, this isn't about your comment at all... just a general observation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a header file that looks something like this:

```
// Common.h

#pragma once

#ifdef COMMON_BUILD
// When building Common.dll, want to export the definition of Pool
#define COMMON_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
// When using Common.dll, want to import the definition of Pool
#define COMMON_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Declarations of shared globals
struct COMMON_EXPORT Pool {
    static int data1;
    static int data2;
};
```

(For more about the `dllimport` and `dllexport` stuff, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx)

Then in your DLL's build, you will want a source file like this:

```
// Common.cpp

#define COMMON_BUILD
#include "Common.h"

int Pool::data1 = 0;
int Pool::data2 = 0;
```

Then, all the DLLs and EXEs that use it should `"#include Common.h"` and link with the Common DLL, and then they can use `Pool::data1`, etc.

Comment: pragma is not standard c++, and the effect is implementation defined. Therefore other answers are better.

Comment: Making DLLs for Windows using C++ is an inherently platform-specific activity. I think you'll find that the other answers don't really work without a whole lot of weird compiler and linker setup.

Comment: Ok, I did it. The common DLL compiles and links fine, but for some reason, the DLL that uses it cannot find a method of the "Pool" and gives a linkage error...

Comment: Maybe you need to add COMMON_EXPORT to the definitions in Common.dll. E.g. `int COMMON_EXPORT Pool::data1 = 0;`

Comment: WOW. THIS IS SO WEIRD! I added a static method which returns the same type as the method of the static member of the class (the one which causes the linking error) returns and now it's fine. I don't even call that fake method or anything...

Answer (score 2):

A `static` declaration of an object makes the object local to the compilation unit.

By using `static` you're creating a `globalPool` object (variable) in every compilation unit where you include the header.

But the way to do what you want is not to just remove the `static`.

Instead define a function providing access to your pool (e.g. a reference to it), and export that function or set of functions from the pool DLL.

Or better  --  **much** better  --  forget the idea. It's a generally bad idea. However, if you really want to do it, and can't see any alternative, then above is how to do it.

And if you do that, perhaps think about thread safety.

And perhaps be aware that dynamic loading of Windows DLLs does not work well with compiler support for thread local variables.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

In the header file you need

```
extern Pool globalPool;
```

Then in a .cpp file in the Common dll, you need

```
Pool globalPool;
```

The extern declaration will put it in the namespace of including modules, and the linker will resolve it to the object in the common dll.